# Installing Jetpack Compose App shows Security Threat

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I'm just learning and experimenting with Jetpack Compose. So when I install the app to my device Huawei p30. I am getting security threat! It's saying the app appears to be malware and posses high risk! There's no issue installing apps that are not using jetpack compose though. What am I doing wrong? Does anybody know what could cause this issue?

[image]

Comment: Do you get this warning with any Composable apps, also with a clean new Compose project deployed to the device?

Comment: Yeah I am getting this error with any Composable app and weirdly it's happening only on Huawei device that I have, I tried on Google Pixel and there's no such warning!